# In C# How do I prevent a PreviewKeyDown Event from being presses multiple times until the certain code has complete?

Tags: c#, winforms

I set up a camera application and my problem is that people can press the button many times, causing the script to mess up:

```
private void mainWinForm_PreviewKeyDown_1(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space) {
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    int count = 0;
    timer.SynchronizingObject = this;
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Elapsed += delegate {
      count++;
      if (count == 1) {
        label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("Countdown_3.txt");
      }
      if (count == 3) {
        label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("Countdown_2.txt");
      }
      if (count == 5) {
        label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("Countdown_1.txt");
      }
      if (count == 7) {
        webcam.Stop();
        label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("ImageCapturedPlusFrozen.txt");
      }
      if (count == 9) {
        label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("IdleForPreview.txt");
        label1.Refresh();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imgVideo.ClientSize.Width, imgVideo.ClientSize.Height)) {
          using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
            g.DrawImage(imgVideo.Image,
              new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
              new Rectangle(0, 0, imgVideo.Image.Width, imgVideo.Image.Height),
              GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
          }
          bmp.Save(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "/ " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss") + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }
      }
      if (count == 20) {
        label1.Text = "Press Button to Start!";
        webcam.Start();
        timer.Stop();
      }
    };
    timer.Start();
  }
}
```

How would I be able to disable the keypress until the timer has finished? I'v tried things like KeyPreview = false; but that won't work!

Comment: unsubscribe from the event then resubscribe once the timer has completed. Simple and elegant as well as more logical

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Unsubscribing and resubscribing to the event handler can become cumbersome and error prone. Better to lock the event handler code with a gate to check to see if the process is already occurring.

Comment: @EtherDragon - sure but it really isnt all that difficult to subscribe and unsubscribe. Same thing with timers for example, some systems do this - same thing with button event handlers in different situations. I still think doing the lock will actually have more headaches in the future, different situations/scenarios

Comment: You are getting yourself into deep trouble with the local *timer* variable.  What do you expect to happen when the user closes the window and the timer is still ticking?  Make it a member of your class instead.  Now it is easier to stop.  And you can simply add `if (timer.Enabled) return;` to ignore key strokes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `bool` flag that will dictate if there is work being done. You then check that flag when the key is pressed.

```
bool flag = false;

private void mainWinForm_PreviewKeyDown_1(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!flag)
        {

                flag = true;
                \\.....
                if (count == 20)
                {
                    \\.......
                    timer.Stop();
                    flag = false;
                }

            timer.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: beat me by a minute! :)

Comment: Quick typer - I was suggesting that they move the timer to a higher scope and leverage that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use a bool to be part of the primary control loop? (initialize it to `true`)

```
if (e.keyCode == Keys.Space && bProcessed)
{
    bProcessed = false;
    // your logic
    bProcessed = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution would be to set your **Button** or **TextBox** control's `Enabled` property.

If that control were called `objCtrl`:

```
private void mainWinForm_PreviewKeyDown_1(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space) {
    objCtrl.Enabled = false;
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    int count = 0;
    timer.SynchronizingObject = this;
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Elapsed += delegate {
      count++;
      if (count == 1) {
        label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("Countdown_3.txt");
      }
      if (count == 3) {
        label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("Countdown_2.txt");
      }
      if (count == 5) {
        label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("Countdown_1.txt");
      }
      if (count == 7) {
        webcam.Stop();
        label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("ImageCapturedPlusFrozen.txt");
      }
      if (count == 9) {
        label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("IdleForPreview.txt");
        label1.Refresh();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imgVideo.ClientSize.Width, imgVideo.ClientSize.Height)) {
          using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
            g.DrawImage(imgVideo.Image,
              new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
              new Rectangle(0, 0, imgVideo.Image.Width, imgVideo.Image.Height),
              GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
          }
          bmp.Save(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "/ " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss") + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }
      }
      if (count == 20) {
        label1.Text = "Press Button to Start!";
        webcam.Start();
        timer.Stop();
        objCtrl.Enabled = true;
      }
    };
    timer.Start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the TIMER from inside the method to outside, so that you can leverage if with several calls to the event handler.

Something like:

```
private var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

private void mainWinForm_PreviewKeyDown_1(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space && !timer.Enabled)
        {
                int count = 0;
                timer.SynchronizingObject = this;
                timer.AutoReset = true; 
                timer.Elapsed += delegate

            {
                count++;
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("Countdown_3.txt");
                }
                if (count == 3)
                {
                    label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("Countdown_2.txt");
                }
                if (count == 5)
                {
                    label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("Countdown_1.txt");
                }
                if (count == 7)
                {
                    webcam.Stop();
                    label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("ImageCapturedPlusFrozen.txt");
                }
                if (count == 9)
                {
                    label1.Text = File.ReadAllText("IdleForPreview.txt");
                    label1.Refresh();
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imgVideo.ClientSize.Width,
                            imgVideo.ClientSize.Height))
                    {
                        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                        {
                            g.DrawImage(imgVideo.Image,
                                        new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                                        new Rectangle(0, 0, imgVideo.Image.Width, imgVideo.Image.Height),
                                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                        }
                        bmp.Save(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "/ " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss") + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
                    }
                }
                if (count == 20)
                {
                    label1.Text = "Press Button to Start!";
                    webcam.Start();
                    timer.Stop();
                }
            };
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
```